# Formal definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$ and total order

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, order-theory

I am looking for a formal definition of the subset of positive real number $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I know the definition of real number and I'm trying to define over $\mathbb{R}$ the symbol $\le$ without the lexicographical order.

This is my idea.

**Definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$**

$\mathbb{R}^+$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\\ \bullet\ 0\notin\mathbb{R}^{+};\\ \\ \bullet\ 1\in\mathbb{R}^{+};\\ \\ \bullet\ x, y\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\iff x+y\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\wedge x\cdot y\in\mathbb{R}^+.$

If the definition is correct, than I can define $\le$ as follow:

$$a\le b\iff b-a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\cup\left\{0\right\}$$

and using the axioms that define the real set $\mathbb{R}$ I can show that it is a totally ordered set under $\le$.

My question: is the definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$ correct? Thanks.

**Edit**: as suggested, the axioms are insufficient to define uniquely $\mathbb{R}^+$. I have to add an axiom:

$\bullet$ If $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\implies x\cdot x\in\mathbb{R}^+$

---

Definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

$\mathbb{R}^+$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $0, -1\notin\mathbb{R}^+$;
2. If $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\implies x^2\in\mathbb{R}^+$;
3. $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^+\iff x+y\in\mathbb{R}^+\wedge x y\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Well, as is, this does not define $\Bbb R^+$ uniquely. For example, $\Bbb N\subseteq\Bbb R$ also satisfies all these properties, as does $\Bbb Q^+$. This is close to an axiomatic description of $\Bbb R^+$, but you're missing trichotomy (and once you have it, you need to make the claim that this definition is satisfied by a *unique* subset of $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I can add an axiom: if $x\in\mathbb{R}\implies x\cdot x\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\implies x\cdot x\in\mathbb R^+$

Comment: You're right, mirko! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key property of the real numbers is:

> A real number is nonnegative if and only if it is a square

As an aside, it turns out that in any orderable ring, the numbers that are nonnegative in *every* ordering of the ring are precisely those numbers that can be written as a sum of squares.

Comment: thank you. I think that the axiom $1\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is useless, but I need to pretend that $-1\notin\mathbb{R}^+$ instead. What do you think?